# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda

Intento realizar una operación aritmética utilizando valores conseguidos de un DataFrame mediante sentencias `df.loc[]`. La sentencia

```
beneficio = (cotz_fin - cotz_ini) * opcion
```

produce el error:

> "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer".

He visto en Internet yen ésta web (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003431/python-typeerror-numpy-float64-object-cannot-be-interpreted-as-an-integer), que el problema podría ser causado por " It is caused by unsupported float index in 1.12.0 and newer versions even if the code should be considered as valid.", recomendando instalar "An int type is expected, not a np.float64 Solution: Try to install numpy 1.11.0".

He comprobado que en mi anaconda3, tengo instalada la versión 1.13.3 de NumPy.

He comprobado también que en mi anaconda 3, el paquete NumPy 1.11.0 no está disponible para ser instalado (`conda search nombredelpaquete`).

En este punto me encuentro bloqueado. ¿Cómo puedo eliminar la versión instalada `numpy-1.13.3` e instalar posteriormente la versión `numpy-1.11.3`, dentro de **Anaconda3**?.

Comment: efueyo creo que deberías hacer los cambios necesarios para evitar la excepción en vez de instalar una versión previa. Si tu problema se debe al uso de floats como indices no es un bug, es un cambio que llevaba planeado bastante tiempo. La indexación de un array con floats es muy poco legible, poco transparente y puede conllevar errores. Dependiendo de que estés haciendo es posible solucionarlos con un simple casting.  Es posible que instalar otra versión de NumPy implique incompatibilidades con librerías que lo tienen como dependencia como pandas mismamente.

Comment: ¿Que obtienes si intentas instalar con `conda install numpy=1.11.3`? De todas formas como te comenté antes creo que sería mejor que proporcionaras un ejemplo mínimo de tu DataFrame con el código necesario para llegar a la línea que te da el error para poder reproducir el problema y  ver como poder solucionarlo sin tener que recurrir a opciones marcadas como "Deprecated".

Comment: @FJSevilla Efectivamente, mi inexperiencia me indujo a cometer el error de no convertir en "float" la variable "opción", número conseguido a través de una sentencia "input". Regla para el futuro: comprobar primero lo más sencillo y básico en el código y no orientarse precipitadamente hacia el texto del error, consultando en Internet. Tenía que haber reflexionado el por qué el error hacia mención a NumPy mientras que en mi código no realizaba la importación de dicho paquete. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi inexperiencia me indujo a cometer el error de no convertir en "float" la variable "opción", número conseguido a través de una sentencia "input". Regla para el futuro: comprobar primero lo más sencillo y básico en el código y no orientarse precipitadamente hacia el texto del error,